# Scanning and storing a simple image in a complex matrix

Tags: r, image, linear-algebra

I have been playing with linear algebra transformations in R, moving around a bunch of points plotted in the complex plane. I have posted the results [here](http://rinterested.github.io/statistics/linear_algebra.html) - the code is linked on the first sentence.

I would like to do the same operations on a real image. Evidently I don't want to get into Fourier transforming the image, or dealing with color or grayscale. I would like to get any old jpeg, turn it into a summarized plot of black and white dots, locate each dot in terms of its position in the complex plane, and then apply the linear algebra operations as I did to my drawing of a house.

The questions are, 1. What is the name for the type of stripped-down, basic black and white image that I am describing? 2. How can I turn a regular jpeg (or other file) into that type of image? How can then store every dot of the thousands of dots the image will contain into a matrix of complex numbers?

Is there software to do this? Is there code in R or python to do it?

Comment: 1) I'd call such an image "rasterized", but the implementations vary. 2) There is `raster` package. 3) R Matrices can hold  complex numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do with those complex vectors, that wouldn't be more easily obtained using standard x,y coordinates, but here goes a possible starting point

```
library(jpeg)

im <- readJPEG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package="jpeg"))
gr <- apply(im, 1:2, mean)
bw <- which(gr < 0.5, arr.ind = TRUE)

conjure_matrix_of_darkness <- function(bw, xlim=c(-2, 2), ylim=c(-2,2)){

  x <- (bw[,1] - min(bw[,1]))/diff(range(bw[,1])) * diff(xlim) + min(xlim)
  y <- (bw[,2] - min(bw[,2]))/diff(range(bw[,2])) * diff(ylim) + min(ylim)
  x+1i*y
}

test <- conjure_matrix_of_darkness(bw)
par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(test, pch=19, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
plot(test*exp(1i*pi), pch=19, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. I guess all I have to do then is `x+1i*y` and store it as a matrix in the complex plane. I think the reason for the complex plane is to be able to rotate the image at will using Euler's equation.

Comment: Just curious... what does `1:2` in `gr` refer to? I see that `im` is a list with two matrices (2), so you... are averaging the value in one of the two matrices with the other?? And then `bw` is some sort of bandwidth?

Comment: 'im' is an array containing the 3 channels corresponding to RGB. So the mean treatment flattens it to a matrix, interpreted as a greyscale. Since you want a black and white result, it needs to be binarised, here with some arbitrary threshold at 0.5 shade of grey.

Comment: Can I change the threshold to make it less dark - more summary, sketch of the actual image?